# Unable to select the value from listbox in selenium

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to select a option from the listbox in a web application.

I am able to locate the element on the application. Also  i used select class and following methods to select the value "AC" from the listbox:

1. select by value.
2. select by index.
3. select by visibletext
4. collected all the elements from the listbox and tried to see if the value "AC" present in the list. The value is present in the listbox.

Now the problem is i am unable to select the value from it by using above methods. I am sure that element is being located by selenium. But when i try to select i am unable to select the value from it. Also it doesnt throw any error on the console..

Can someone please help me with a solution?

Comment: please post your HTML and the source code that's not working, and if you got error messages, then also these error-messages

Comment: hi..thanks for your response...I figured it out.. The solution is :
browser.findelement(by.id("cbOmake")).sendkeys "AC"..... Instead of select class i used sendkeys and it worked...